# Can someone explain to me what the "mini dump" error mean in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, error

I am struggling to understand what the error "Crash dumped: mini dump written to C:" means in QGIS. I am working with layers stored on a network drive. Whenever I try to read in a few particular .asc files QGIS returns the above error and closes.

These layers were working fine until I did some processing of one of them in SAGA and saved out to a new file. Now I can't read any of the original or processed layers, or any new .asc files exported from SAGA for that matter. The original layers still work fine on all other computers in the department, so they are not corrupted, it is something to do with my version.

Comment: a mini dump is a log file that is created when qgis crashes unexpectedly. It might require a fresh install to read your original files.

Comment: Thanks Mapperz, I was worried that a fresh install might be needed. All those plugins to find again! Any idea what causes this kind of problem to arise in the first place so I can avoid the same thing happening again? Seems strange that layers can be working one minute and then can never be opened again.

Comment: @Mapperz Can these log files be safely deleted from the temp folder?

Comment: @user25976 yes they can.

Comment: @mapperz It seems your comment could be transformed into an answer. People may think it's an unanswered question.

Comment: @ThomasG77 not really a GIS issue/problem but software problem yes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should probably be a bug report, if the issue can be reproduced.