# QGIS 3 won't open in Windows 10 pro, how to fix?

Tags: qgis, installation

I have installed QGIS 3 in Windows 10 pro 64 bit, but it won't open the GUI. This is the error:

[image: qgis-bin.exe aplication has stopped working]

And then this:

[image]

Some specifications:

- I had installed QGIS 2.18, and it ran perfectly.
- I had installed the latest QGIS 3 under "Program Files" folder and also in the root C:.
- I installed with OSGeo4W software and with QGIS desktop .exe, load to QGIS web page.
- I run other software like PostgreSQL, GeoServer, GeoNetwork and ArcGIS  on the PC.

Comment: Did you check downloaded file up with md5sum utility?

Comment: did qgis create a mini-dump crash report? like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234618/what-is-a-crash-dumped-crash-minidump

Comment: Have a laptop with windows 10 pro and QGIS 3.0 running (english US settings) may be a problem/bug with the spanish version?

Comment: Run the OSGeo4W shell and type QGIS in it. It should run QGIS 3.0. I think it's a question of path settings.

Answer (score 4):

The comments were very helpful and I can now open QGIS 3 without a problem. I have done it in two ways:

With the help of Mapperz, look for Qgis-rel-dev-g 7.4.0.bat inside the installation of QGIS 3 and this run.

[image]

With the help of Techie_Gus, I can run QGIS 3 without problems from the OSgeo4w terminal.

Both ways work well.

[image]

I don't consider the language likely to be the problem, if not more the path as Techie_Gus said , because I did run QGIS 3 in another session.

I'll be trying to do what Xunilk says, to define the specific error.

The main problem was solved, and I could run QGIS 3, also, I think it is a path problem perhaps in the registry of W10, I will checked the environment variables.