# QGIS 3 won't work on my Windows 10 computer anymore

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, windows-10

After making a rather lenghty SQL query, QGIS 3 started not working properly and after a while it finally ceased to work completely. Trying to start up it back again won't do anything and it will always redirect me to the crash log report.

For some reason this problem is only affecting any instance of QGIS 3 installed in my Windows 10 computer as I tried running QGIS 2.18 which was previously installed on my computer and I haven't came across any problems so far. Running SAGA or GRASS alone also work perfectly.

I've tried erasing any trace of QGIS 3 within my system and trying to reinstall it back again, but the problem persists.

This is one of the crash logs the crash report sent me:

```
Stack Trace


QThread::currentThread :
QObjectPrivate::~QObjectPrivate :
_CallSettingFrame handlers.asm:50
__FrameHandler3::FrameUnwindToState frame.cpp:1159
__FrameHandler3::FrameUnwindToEmptyState risctrnsctrl.cpp:241
__InternalCxxFrameHandler frame.cpp:321
__CxxFrameHandler3 risctrnsctrl.cpp:267
RtlpExecuteHandlerForUnwind :
RtlUnwindEx :
_C_specific_handler :
RtlpExecuteHandlerForException :
RtlDispatchException :
RtlRaiseException :
RaiseException :
_CxxThrowException throw.cpp:75
qBadAlloc :
QString::reallocData :
QSettings::qt_metacast :
QSettings::endGroup :
QSettings::sync :
QThreadPool::maxThreadCount :
QUrlQuery::setQueryItems :
QXmlStreamStringRef::~QXmlStreamStringRef :
QSettings::QSettings :
QgsSettings::QgsSettings :
QgsPluginRegistry::restoreSessionPlugins :
QgisApp::QgisApp :
main :
BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :
```

Comment: Probably a hint about the operating system used would be helpful for those able to answer you.

Comment: Right, I'm working on the latest version of Windows 10.

Comment: Did you try (if installed) to use windows sandbox or another sandbox tool like sandboxie to install QGIS there?

Comment: I haven't and I have none of them installed, It was working all up until yesterday so I never thought it could be a compatibility issue.

Comment: OK, but you have enough free memory?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273078/qgis-3-wont-open-in-windows-10-pro-how-to-fix

Comment: You mean RAM or disk space? The answer is yes to both, I have it installed on my SSD and I have 8 gb of RAM which has been always enough

Comment: How did you try "erasing any trace of QGIS 3"?

Comment: Standalone QGIS installation or OSGeo4W installation? Did you try both installing routines?

Comment: I tried starting up  through the OSGeo shell yesterday too, It redirects me to the crash log everytime too. I can't find that .bat file they're talking about neither within my QGIS bin directory, I guess that has something to do with my problem.

Comment: Regarding your other questions: I tried uninstalling it and then deleting all folders that could be left within program files directories, then trying to reinstall it.

Comment: Strange - let's hope there are people out here with better ideas...

Comment: Did you delete or rename your QGIS folder in C:\Users\yourusernamehere\AppData\Roaming\QGIS and the same for Local?

Comment: Silly of me, but I hadn't removed the roaming folder. Doing so fixed everything. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the folder within `C:\Users\yourusernamehere\AppData\Roaming\QGIS` fixed the issue.